# m.2 vs ssd which is better

Tags: laptop, memory, hard-disk, ssd

I have a HP laptop

I want to upgrade my HP 15 ay122ne (i7-7500U 8GB RAM 1TB HDD 4GB graphics)

Can anyone please help me with the following:

- For max performance, which is better, a 2.5" SSD or m.2 SSD ?
- How much RAM can I upgrade on this laptop- can I insert another 16 GB DDR4 into this laptop ..like whats the maximum it can support running windows 10 ?

My laptop isn't slow or anything but I want to take out the HDD inside it and use it as an external storage device in a USB HDD enclosure, and also to experience how fast SSD works (I have never used a laptop with SSD).

Comment: It seems like you've got a few different questions going on here, some of which are appropriate for this site, some of which are not. This site doesn't deal with the first question, since it's a tech-support type question (in the future, superuser.com is a better place to go.) The second would be acceptable, but you've kinda phased it more like a support request than a hardware recommendation request. The third question is simply unrelated. While I could simple answer each part of your question, the spirit of your question doesn't really align too well with the site.

Comment: Right now, your question is sort of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'm going to suggest you rewrite your question as a general upgrade question. Explain what trouble you're having (what's running slow, what you want more of, why) and we'll pick out the best things to help you for your use case. This can include what SSD and RAM, if necessary.

Comment: That said, I don't want to just close this and leave you hanging. So, regarding your questions: 1. Yes, but there's multiple kinds (can go over this in more detail in a later answer.) 2. In general, drives should only be RAID'd if they're the exact same type of drive. However, there's no really no harm in having two drives installed if you want the extra storage; however, it won't really help performance, unless you cache things from a slower drive on a faster one. 3. I believe 16 GB, but possibly 32 GB.

Comment: @JMY1000 This was my first question on this site. I posed the three questions for help with upgrade. If it even is a XY question ..how would I even ask about m2 SSD if I wouldn't  first know if it supports m2, and what is my third question unrelated to ??

Comment: @JMY1000 anyways I tried to edit the question a bit, Hope it is acceptable now.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the rough welcome, SE's rules can be pretty confusing. It's closer, but I'm still left wondering **why** you want/need to upgrade your laptop. Again, can you explain what problem is motivating you to upgrade? Is something running slow? Is there a particular program that isn't performing as well as you want? Are you just out of storage space? Go ahead and add that info to your question and I'll be happy to re-open it.

Comment: @JMY1000 I edited the question again

Comment: The maximum amount of memory that HP specifies for this laptop is 2x8GB. But I see no reason why 2x16GB should not work, the CPU can definitely handle it. Note that if you add a 16GB stick to your existing 8GB one, you will end up with asymmetric dual-channel. This can have a negative impact on performance, compared to symmetric dual-channel with 2 identical DIMMs. The extent of the performance impact -as always- depends on your workload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://www.performance-computer.com/learn/ssds-compared/

SATA3 Hard Drive        SATA3 SSD       NVMe SSD
~100 MB/s Read          530 MB/s Read   3,500 MB/s Read
~100 MB/s Write         500 MB/s Write  3,000 MB/s Write
```

M.2 is a **form factor**, it technically has nothing to do with speed or performance.

You can get m.2 storage (to replace your disk or ssd) and this storage can connect either via the **SATA3 protocol** or **NVMe protocol**.

SATA3 is limited to 6 gbit/sec, which then connects to the PCIe bus.

NVMe is a protocol allowing a direct connection to the PCIe bus, it not limited to the 6gbiy/sec transfer rate limitation of the sata3 interface, and is thus faster.

https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/m2-with-pcie-or-sata

using an m.2 form factor storage device having a sata3 interface, will be no different than using a typical 2.5" form factor solid state disk (SSD) which also using the sata3 interface.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Intels manual for you laptop](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05087748), it does support an M.2 drive, but only one using SATA and not NVMe.
The performance difference compared to a conventional 2.5" SATA will be minimal.
The illustrations seem to depict that you can only use *either* an M.2 SATA SSD, or a 2.5" SATA drive.

HDDs won't bring any performance advantage. M.2 vs 2.5" SSDs will also be close, though 2.5" SSDs tend to be cheaper for the same capacity.

Also, according to the same manual (pg. 31), you laptop seems to have two memory slots, and lists 8 GB, 4 GB and 2 GB modules as compatible. That would allow you to upgrade to 2x8 GB modules.
Single (or dual) 16 GB modules *may* work, but there's not offical guarantee they will.

Comment: according to the manual you shared, on page 10 it mentions that it supports up to 16GB in a dual channel...mine is core i7 seventh gen

Comment: is NVMe a relatively newer tech and could it be possible that this is an old manual and thats why they have not mentioned about NVMe ??

Comment: @DavidKent Right, those are also visible on page 31. I updated the answer.
NVMe uses PCIe lanes for the SSD instead of SATA - it's a definitive hardware (in-)capability. Sadly the manual doesn't mention it, and the pictures M.2 SSD also has the "key" for SATA SSDs.